# Problemas con mi PROCEDURE en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure

El problema es el siguiente:

Trato de realizar una comparación con el `IF`, en el cual la unidad que ingresa el usuario es mayor con la unidad que tiene en la tabla de productos. Con la `TRANSACTIONS` debo cancelar si ocurre esa comparación con el `rollback` para no ingresar ningún valor a las tablas.

Un ejemplo:

Tengo un producto con 500 unidades con una id de 1, llega un usuario y quiere ese producto e ingresa que quiere 550 unidades, la TRANSACTION debe verificar eso y dejar que no ingrese ningún valor.

Les dejare como están mis tablas por si existe algún error:

```
create TABLE venta( 
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
fecha DATE,nombreCliente VARCHAR(60), 
domicilio VARCHAR(60));

CREATE TABLE producto( 
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
stock INT, precio double);

CREATE TABLE detalleVenta(
 idVenta INT, 
 FOREIGN KEY(idVenta) REFERENCES venta(id), 
 cantidad int, 
 idProducto INT, 
 FOREIGN KEY (idProducto) REFERENCES producto(id));
```

Mi Procedure donde esta el error que les comento.

```
 delimiter ##
 create procedure sp_vender  (
 in p_nombreCliente varchar(60),
 in p_domicilio varchar(60),
 in p_idProducto int,
 in p_cantidad int
 )
 begin
 declare id int;
 declare d_cant int;
  start transaction;
  
 select stock into d_cant from producto where id = p_idProducto;

  insert into venta(fecha, nombreCliente, domicilio) values(curdate(), p_nombreCliente, p_domicilio);
  set id = last_insert_id();
  insert into detalleventa(idVenta, cantidad, idProducto)values(id, p_cantidad, p_idProducto);
  
  if p_cantidad > d_cant then
rollback;
  else
   commit; 
  end if;
 end ##
 delimiter ;
```

Comment: No entendí. Se agradece que expliques sin demasiados rodeos lo que quieres lograr y el problema que tienes. Tu explicación es confusa porque mezclas el qué con el cómo. Interesa para quienes van a responder entender el qué, no el cómo.

Comment: Ahora? Creo que se entiende bien

Comment: @Reoni ¿por que simplemente haces los `INSERT` solo cuando `if p_cantidad > d_cant then` ? y en el `else` nada

Comment: No se entiende. Sigues mezclando el qué con el cómo. Para entender un problema el cómo no importa. El cómo serviría para ver el error en el código. Pongo un ejemplo: *Trato de realizar una comparación mediante con el IF...* el qué es que hay que hacer una **comparación**, pero no explicas con claridad **en qué consiste esa comparación**, sino que pasas al cómo: *mediante con el IF*. La pregunta se entendéis mejor si escribieras algo así:

Comment: ... "Trato de comparar que tal cosa no sea mayor qué tal cosa... tal cosa viene de tal sitio y tal otra cosa viene de tal otro sitio. Si la comparación es verdadera hay que hacer tal cosa, de lo contrario hay que hacer tal otra".... Y luego pones el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No uses el rollback o el commit, mas bien trata de retornar un mensaje donde indiques el resultados, sino, y si es necesario el commit reemplaza el return por rollback y al final del else el commit.

```
create procedure sp_vender  
(
 in p_nombreCliente varchar(60),
 in p_domicilio varchar(60),
 in p_idProducto int,
 in p_cantidad int
)
begin
    declare id int;
    declare d_cant int;
    start transaction;

    select stock into d_cant from producto where id = p_idProducto;

    if p_cantidad > d_cant then
        return;
    else
        insert into venta(fecha, nombreCliente, domicilio) values(curdate(), p_nombreCliente, p_domicilio);
        set id = last_insert_id();
        insert into detalleventa(idVenta, cantidad, idProducto)values(id, p_cantidad, p_idProducto);
    end if;
 end ##
 delimiter ;
```